# Python package only working for root user not for others | Using linux suse

Tags: python, linux, pip, package

I have installed Python package  'forcast' using root and it runs fine but all other Linux users wont be able to see this package or import it in code .

Please help me, i have checked  /usr/lib/ all package are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that users do not have permission to access the files? check the access modes to the files in the package - you need +rx for directories and +r for files.

Another option is that this path is not searched by default, and you need to add it to PYTHONPATH for the users.

Comment: Thank You for your time and response Bartek ,  directories are with +rx and files with +r . when i ssh using my  user  and look for the package , it says no package with this found.   How do i add it to pythonpath for my user.   You time and efforts are appreciated

Comment: It depends on your shell, in bash it would be: export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/package